# load ecmascript module (.mjs file) as main entry of nodejs cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, es6-modules, mjs

is there a way to use an ecmascript module file as the main entry file to a cli exported using the package.json bin entry?

i guess i would need to somehow provide the --experimental-modules flag, but i can not figure out a way to do this without wrapping the mjs file into a js file and then calling the mjs file via

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// pseudocode
child_process.spawn(
  'node', 
  ['--experimental-modules', 'bin.mjs'], 
  { stdio: 'inherit' }
)
```

given the overhead of calling child_process.spawn, i would love to be able to replace those wrappers in my libraries.

edit:
please not that my cli has to be installable as an executable using npm i -g, which, afaik, makes it impossible to pass any command line flags to the node process (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140345/load-ecmascript-module-mjs-file-as-main-entry-of-nodejs-cli/56141773#56141773) that i will not be able to use)

edit2: 
figured i should leave a link to the related library here too [@magic/cli](https://github.com/magic/cli), this is my current approach (i include a bin.js file that child_process.spawns a mjs file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node 13 enables `--experimental-modules` by default, so `#!/usr/bin/env node` is enough. However, a warning is still emitted.

> `(node:23260) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.`

Comment: thanks!

https://github.com/magic/cli
has been updated to leverage that fact by now,
i just remembered this question and went here to answer it, and, as usual, so has already done so.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the `esm` module and then require it when running the code i.e. instead of `--experimental-modules`, you can use `-r esm` instead. You would then run your code as `node -r esm bin.mjs`.

Comment: this, whilst entirely valid and usable, would force the consumers of my cli to always type node -r esm cli.mjs though.

and, unfortunately, in the case of globally installed cli's this would not help at all.

thanks for the answer though :)